# JavaScript: Best way to check if duplicate value for a particular key exists in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, for example:

```
[
                {
                    id: 1243,
                    name: "Cola",
                    isLocationAssign: true,
                    location: 8
                },
                {
                    id: 1243,
                    name: "Cola",
                    isLocationAssign: true,
                    qty: 30,
                    location: 8
                }
            ]
```

In the above array of objects we have the same value for `location`. What would be the best way to find out if duplicate values for a particular key exist in an array of objects? I can't think past multiple loops

Comment: Groupby should do the trick

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

````js
let array = [
                {
                    id:1234,
                    name: "Cola",
                    isLocationAssign: true,
                    location: 8
                },
                {
                    id: 1234,
                    name: "Cola",
                    isLocationAssign: true,
                    qty: 30,
                    location: 8
                },
                                {
                    id: 1235,
                    name: "Cola",
                    isLocationAssign: true,
                    qty: 30,
                    location: 8
                },
                {
                    id: 1235,
                    name: "Cola",
                    isLocationAssign: true,
                    qty: 30,
                    location: 7
                }
                ]
            
let duplicatedIdsItems = array.filter(a => a.id === 1234);
console.log(duplicatedIdsItems)

var valueArr = duplicatedIdsItems.map(function(item){ return item.location });
var isDuplicate = valueArr.some(function(item, idx){ 
    return valueArr.indexOf(item) != idx 
});```
````